# Create enum with entries associated to classes

Tags: java, generics, enums, polymorphism, instanceof

Supposing I have several specific classes which all extend one abstract class, like so:

```
public abstract AbstractClass {
  // abstract stuff here
}

public FirstSpecificClass extends AbstractClass {
  // specific stuff here
}

public SecondSpecificClass extends AbstractClass {
  // specific stuff here
}
```

I need to create an `enum` elsewhere in which each entry is connected (associated?) with one of the specific classes; to that end, I am passing the specific class as a constructor parameter and storing it as a private field within the enum (I've also provided a getter method for that field). I also need to create a static method which takes an instance of one of the specific classes as an argument and returns the appropriate enum element (or null). I will do this by looping over each enum entry and using `instanceof` in combination with the getter for the private field mentioned previously. This is my attempt:

```
public enum Types {
  FIRST(FirstSpecificClass.class),   // line 2
  SECOND(SecondSpecificClass.class); // line 3

  private Class<AbstractClass> classType;

  private Types(Class<AbstractClass> classType) {
    this.classType = classType;
  }

  public Class<AbstractClass> getClassType() {
    return this.classType;
  }

  public static Types fromTypeInstance(AbstractClass instance) {
    for(Types t : Types.values())
      if(instance instanceof t.getClassType()) return t; // line 17
    return null;
  }
}
```

I seem to misunderstanding how to store the class type as a field so that it can be returned and used in the `instanceof` check later. This code is producing several compile-time errors:

- (line 2 of the enum): The constructor `Types(Class<FirstSpecificClass>)` is undefined
- (line 3 of the enum): The constructor `Types(Class<SecondSpecificClass>)` is undefined
- (line 17 of the enum): Incompatible operand types `boolean` and `Class<AbstractClass>`

I am not usually a Java programmer, and my understanding of generics and `instanceof` is fuzzy at best, although I do have a pretty firm grasp on the concept of OOP. How can I resolve these errors and achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, generics are invariant.  This means that a `Class<FirstSpecificClass>` is not a `Class<AbstractClass>`, even if a `FirstSpecificClass` is an `AbstractClass`.

You can work around this by explicitly allowing subtypes with an upper bound wildcard.  Add `? extends` before your `AbstractClass` type argument where needed.

```
private Class<? extends AbstractClass> classType;

private Types(Class<? extends AbstractClass> classType) {
   this.classType = classType;
}

public Class<? extends AbstractClass> getClassType() {
   return this.classType;
}
```

Additionally, you must specify the type directly in the source code for the `instanceof` operator, so this doesn't compile:

```
if(instance instanceof t.getClassType())
```

You can use the [`Class` object's `isInstance` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) instead, for a runtime solution:

```
if(t.getClassType().isInstance(instance))
```

Comment: aha! thank you! this solves the type incompatibility in the constructor. i am still getting an error on the `instanceof` check, because the right-hand argument isn't supposed to actually be a Class object (apparently it needs to be a "type"). how do i cast that as appropriate in order to achieve the instanceof check?

Comment: I had noticed that error too, and I updated my answer.

Comment: i will accept this as soon as the timer allows me to.